# Different behavior in two command prompt instances due to parallels?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallels

Have a macbook with Parallels on it, running Windows 7.  Installed Python on my "C" Drive, my windows drive (virtual drive?), and followed the instructions to add it to my Path System variable.  Accessing the C drive from the start menu (typing in cmd.exe), python is recognized and starts right up (right pic).  Accessing in from a command prompt created by holding shift and right-clicking and choosing the "Open Command Window Here" option, python isn't recognized (left pic).  What gives?

[image]

Comment: What does `echo %PATH%` give you in both?

Comment: It's working now.  An the Path System variables match.  I cannot get it to replicate the error - for right now at least.  Weird.